# Why did Babylonians/Persians use the ascension year method?

Tags: persia, bible, ancient-babylon, hebrew

> [12] Then Jehoiachin king of Judah, his mother, his servants, his princes, and his officers went out to the king of Babylon; and the king of Babylon, in the eighth year of his reign, took him prisoner. *2 Kings 24:12 NKJV*

According to the Old Testament, the siege of Jerusalem in 597 BCE took place in the 8th year of the reign of Nebuchadnezzar II. The [Nebuchadnezzer Chronicle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nebuchadnezzar_Chronicle), however, which mentions the same event, dates it in his seventh year

Scholars generally say that this is because the Babylonians/Persians used the "ascension-year" method of dating regnal years, meaning that the first regnal year of a king would begin in the first month the following year he ascended the throne.

To those who are learned in this topic, is there a reason why the Babylonians/Persians reckoned the regnal years of their kings this way?

Comment: Not an answer because I don't have a source, but a logical reason might be to avoid double-counting the year (thus making it easier to back-calculate, if you know the lengths of the kings' reigns, how many years ago an event dated "Year X of King Y" actually was). Whereas with the non-accession-year system, you'd have to subtract 1 year for each king _unless_ he happened to ascend to the throne on the first day of the new year, which complicates things.